# How to increase font size for messages in Telegram desktop client on Windows?

Tags: windows, fonts, telegram-messenger

In Telegram Windows desktop client, how to increase font size for messages?

All the tutorials I found online are for mobile apps which aren't applicable to the Windows desktop client:

https://www.google.com/search?q=telgram+font+size

There is no place to find 'Text Settings' for adjusting font size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two answers for Windows App.

1. Well behaved apps. Go to Settings and set the overall Scale (higher for high resolution screens). I use 125% for this setting.

   Search for Make Text Bigger and use the Text scale for all well behaved apps. I use 110%. This affects text and icon text size.
2. If the app is not well behaved (I have some), Windows Text setting does not affect these. Some have their own settings and some do not.

So try the above and see if it changes Telegram.

Answer (score 9):

This procedure might do it:

- Click the 3 lines (the hamburger) in the upper left corner
- Select Settings
- Scroll down to default interface scale
- Select desired percentage
- It will prompt you to restart the program, select OK

Comment: This changes the size of all UI elements, not just the text